# Python Not found error when importing from different folder

Tags: python, importerror

My goal is to pull the class named `Ui_mainForm` from the file in the `Forms` folder. But I am getting an error like this:

> No module named 'Forms'

The file directory is as follows:

[image]

Code:

```
from Forms.Ui_mainForm import Ui_mainForm
```

---

**Latest status:**

[image]

I arranged it this way. Also the `__init__.py` files are hollow.

Code:

```
from ..Forms.Ui_mainForm import Ui_mainForm
```